# How to insert water softener drain pipe

Tags: drain, water-softener

I'm installing water softener in my garage .. there are two drain pipes already there, which one to use and how to open these? Any pointers on these?[image: water drainage]

Comment: The upper pipe seems to be capped with the cap likely glued on. If it doesn't come off by hand, you will likely have to carefully cut it off, leaving enough pipe to attach your drain piping.

Comment: The lower pipe seems to be a threaded "clean out" where you unscrew/screw the center plug by fitting a tool into the rectangular slot in the middle. This is likely there to allow future access to the pipe for cleaning, so best to leave it as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottom one appears to be a 2" clean out. The end cap looks like it in need of repair or at least loose.

The top looks like a 1-1/2" drain and you would normally cut off that end cap unless you could just twist it off because the installer didn't glue it on because it's just a drain. You will need to do a little investigation to confirm this. Do you have the construction plans? You'll have to open them up to be sure.

Comment: Zooming in on the picture, one is able to read '2" cleanout' printed right on the ring on the lower pipe.